# Set up pygame mixer

Tags: python, pygame

When I try to start pygame.mixer it results in:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound("scream.ogg")

sounda.play()
```

> No protocol specified No protocol specified No protocol specified
>   xcb_connection_has_error() returned True

What to do? It always worked on other raspberrys.
I allready checked the audio configuration and ran some other code..

Comment: Your exact code works for me with a known-good `.ogg` file.  Does you file play OK otherwise? What OS Python & Pygame versions are you using?

Comment: Does the user running the code have sound-output permissions?  Are you using bluetooth audio? Do you need `jackd` running?  This seems like a rPi issue rather than a PyGame issue.  You might have better luck asking on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Allright, the thing was, i had the code running on a RPi 2 and it worked,
The RPi 2 was damaged somehow.
When i changed the SD Card to the RPi3 that error came.
 I reinstalled the whole System then it worked.
All other codes ran correct.